# Query from file using awk

Tags: awk, compare

I have a file of 6 columns:
$cat data1.txt

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,292,14292
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02,45014,50755
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,72,22322
123726139528,02,3532810125937435,639f02,8,3562
```

I have a second file(data2) of 3 columns

```
64340,5616,abc  
64341,5616,def  
64342,5616,ghi  
64344,5616,hjk  
64345,5616,lmn  
64346,5616,opq
```

I need to compare the last column of data1 with 1st or 2nd column of data2.If there's a match, the output file data3 will have 3rd field of data2.E.g:

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,292,14292,abc
123715942138,01,3538710295145500,639f02,45014,50755,def
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,72,22322,ghi
123726139528,02,3532810125937435,639f02,8,3562,lmn
```

Thanks.

Bernie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the second file is a small lookup file and the first file is a large data file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}

NR == FNR {
    lookup1[$1] = lookup2[$2] = $3
    next
}

{
    if (lookup1[$NF]) {
        $(NF+1) = lookup1[$NF]
        print
    }
    else if (lookup2[$NF]) {
        $(NF+1) = lookup2[$NF]
        print
    }
}
```

To run it:

```
$ ./script.awk data2.txt data1.txt
```

Using this as `data2.txt`:

```
14292,333,zzz
555,777,nnn
222,22322,xxx
111,444,yyy
```

and the `data1.txt` from your question, the result:

```
123711184642,02,3583090366663629,639f02,292,14292,zzz
123711616258,02,3548370476972758,639f02,72,22322,xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

*join* the two tables on the relevant fields then print the last field of the result using *awk*

To find matches on the first field of file 2:

```
join -1 76 -2 1 -t, data1.txt data2.txt | awk `BEGIN{FS=","}{print($NF)}`
```

Then match on the second field of file 2 and concatenate the two sets of results:

```
join -1 76 -2 2 -t, data1.txt data2.txt | awk `BEGIN{FS=","}{print($NF)}`
```

Chapter 4 of *The AWK Programming Language* covers this kind of stuff really well, including writing a version of *join* in AWK if it's not available on your system.

Comment: Should have used "awk -F, " as the to get rid of the clunky way of setting FS in BEGIN.

Comment: I assume you mean "6" instead of "76". By the way, the data files will need to be sorted by their `join` fields and the output fields will need to be selected using the `-o` option of `join` or using AWK, since the OP wants only field 3 from the second data file in the output along with the whole record from the first file (your command only prints one field). Also, you need to use single quotes instead of backticks. There's nothing wrong with setting `FS` in `BEGIN` especially if you need to set `OFS` to the same thing.